# Insert gzip files into android device

Tags: android

In my android application i want to load a gzip file along with my application into device.
I tried placing it in /data/data/mypackage but its not getting loaded into the device.
I also tried placing in raw folder but still not working.

Is there any way that i can get this done?

Please share your valuable suggestions.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it better to put it into "assets" folder, a file access can looks like:

```
InputStream is = new GZIPInputStream(context.getAssets().open("your file name.gz"));
```

Comment: Its not working i tried that too.Do the file placed in data/data of ddms store in device